# Show $241|\binom{240}{120}$.

Tags: binomial-coefficients

Here is what I found: $\binom{241}{120}*\frac{121}{241}=\binom{240}{120}$. I'm not sure how to continue.

Comment: It doesn't. Check the prime factors of $\binom{240}{120}$.

Answer (score 8):

241 is prime, and the numerator of the binomial is $240!$, so the question is obviously incorrect.